# changing the column names of a concated dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

[image: DataFrame]

This is my dataframe that has column names 0 and 0. I need to change it to x and y. Is there any possible solution.

```
a = pd.DataFrame(array_x)
b = pd.DataFrame(array_y)
c = pd.concat([a,b],axis = 1)
```

This is my code

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: instead of the column name 0,  I have to get X and for the another column Y. Just the column name i need to change

Comment: add  ``c.columns = ['x', 'y']`` at the end, as in the link @retatu suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign column name to your dataframe.

like this...

```
c.columns = ['x','y']
```